# Mac software update app automatically open if update are already downloaded and install and require user

Tags: terminal, script

Script to Lauch Mac software update app automatically.
eq if we have monterey12.3 and on softwareupdate.plist shows availble as 12.4 then open mac software update app

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: for software update for users mac machines we use softwareupdate -a-i but users don't reboot their devices or when they receive notification also they ignore.can you please help me with script that can lauch SU screen if updates are ready to install.